# How to use a launch configuration as a template in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to use a launch configuration in eclipse as a "template" such that I can just right click the java file containing the main class and run/debug it?

**Launch configuration:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAr1K.png]

I want to use this for running tests (we do not use any frameworks like JUnit) which are all in separate java files. The launch configurations mainly have different environments (particularly the environment variables set) to control whether to run the test with logging/tracing on, etc. Right now, in order to run different tests using different environment variables, I have to keep changing the main class based on the test I want to run.

Comment: See https://projects.eclipse.org/development_effort/launch-configuration-templates

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can create a [prototype](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/Plan/Launch_Configuration_Templates) as a template. There are several steps necessary:

1. create a prototype configuration
2. create a configuration
3. select the prototype tab + set the prototype
4. at the end it should look like this and you can set some attributes

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, if I want to run "myTest1.java" then I have to create a new launch configuration first then link it to a prototype to get the env variables? I was thinking something along the lines of: I can just right click "myTest1.java" then run/debug as then select the prototype or something like that.

Comment: You got it right. But if it works for you, you can start the program and then edit the configuration you have created. I suspect that this is not possible to select the prototype after the start.